# How get values from UItable View cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a  `TableView` with custom cell with a `CheckBox`, A label and a `TextField`. I want to get label text and `TextField` text of all the cells that I have `CheckBox` checked. How can I achieve it. whenever I scroll the `TableViewCell` index changed so I am not able to use `rowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: You'll have to change your approach to this. A `UITableView` is not there to provide data, but to present data (that's why it's asking the datasource in order to present & configure the cells). So, since the data are already provided by your datasource, you will have to query _that_ object and not the tableview. I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: when you select checkbox, you can call method and pass indexPath. Use indexPath.row and get value from array objectAtIndex

Comment: Read carefully what @Alladinian wrote -- it's critical to using TableViews properly.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.  Alladinian, your solution is tricky but works ;)

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you will have to use array to keep track of which cells are checked. So declare `NSMutableArray *checkedCells;` variable and initialize it. In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` write following lines :

```
UITableViewCell *cell=  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell.radioChecked)
{
    /*Create a object with textField and label value here.and add that object in checkedCells here*/
}
else
{
    /*remove regarding cell object from checkedCells here*/
}
```

This way you will get properties of cells which are checked.

Comment: You should not need to create a new array.  You should already have, in your dataSource, an array of custom objects or dictionaries representing the rows in the table, and you just update that.